# Prove that there is a one to one relationship between the union of two one to one sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove that if $f$ is one to one on $A$ and on $B$ and $f(A \cap B) = \emptyset$ is empty then $f$ is one to one on $A \cup B$.

Answer (score 3):

The statement is not true.

Let $A=\{a\}$ and $B=\{b\}$ be singletons with $a\neq b$ and let $f$ be a *constant* function. Then $f$ is injective on $A$ and on $B$ and $A\cap B=\emptyset$ and consequently $f(A\cap B)=\emptyset$. However function $f$ is not injective on $A\cup B=\{a,b\}$.

Things become different if it is demanded that $f(A)\cap f(B)=\emptyset$. Then it can indeed be proved that $f$ will be injective on $A\cup B$. Like this:

Let $x,y\in A\cup B$ with $z=f\left(x\right)=f\left(y\right)$. Without
loss of generality assume that $x\in A$. Here $y\in B$ would lead
to $z\in f\left(A\right)\cap f\left(B\right)$ so contradicts that
$f\left(A\right)\cap f\left(B\right)=\emptyset$. So we are allowed
to conclude that $y\in A$. Then the injectivity of $f$ on $A$ implies
that $x=y$.

Comment: By the last statement that proves that A union B is one to one?

Comment: I started with $x,y\in A\cup B$ s.t. $f(x)=f(y)$. I ended with conclusion $x=y$. That means that injectivity has been proved, and this for function $f$ on set $A\cup B$.

Comment: @Morgan: It doesn't prove that "$A\cup B$ is one-to-one", because that claim doesn't make sense. "One-to-one" is not a property of _sets_ but a property of _functions_. What drhab proves is that $f$ is one-to-one on $A\cup B$. (Since you're also making this wording mistake in the title of the question, it looks like you have an underlying misunderstanding that you ought to correct).

Answer (score 1):

(Edited)

As pointed out by Henning, the condition should be $f(A) \cap f(B) = \phi$, rather than $f(A \cap B) = \phi$. The proof is:

Let $x, \ y \in A \cup B$ and suppose $f(x) = f(y)$. We have 4 cases.

$1)$ $x \in A$ and $y \in A$. Then since $f$ is one-to-one on $A$, we are done.

$2)$ $x \in B$ and $y \in B$. Like $1)$.

$3)$ $x \in A$ and $y \in B$. This is impossible because $x \in A$ gives $f(x) \in f(A)$, but $f(y) = f(x)$, so $f(y) \in f(A)$. But $y \in B$, so $f(y) \in f(B)$, a contradiction because $f(A) \cap f(B) = \phi$.

$4)$ Similar argument to $3)$.

Therefore the only possible cases are $1)$ and $2)$, and both gave us $x = y$.

Comment: Just to clarify for the OP, case 4 is for $x \in B$ and $y \in A$.

Comment: In your case (3), your conclusion $y=a$ doesn't follow. You have no assumption that $y\in A$, so $f$ being one-to-one on $A$ doesn't restrict what $y$ (_outside_ $A$) can be.

Comment: I just realized that after reading your answer. You are right, and the condition which would make sense is $f(A) \cap f(B) = \phi$.

Answer (score 1):

This is not true.  A counterexample would be $f(x)=x^2$, $A=[-2,-1]$, $B=[1,2]$.

Perhaps the not-entirely-sensical condition $f(A\cap B)=\emptyset$ should have been $f(A)\cap f(B)=\emptyset$? Then it would be true.